# Vue computed properties lost on hard refresh

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have a sub component that gets some data passed in via props and some via computed properties. It works fine until I do a hard page reload; then it fails at the 'this.attributes.manufacturer' which returns undefined. Anyone suggest a way to fix this please?

```
<template>
  <span>
    {{ manufacturer | htmlDecode }}
  </span>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      attributes: 'extraCart/attributeListByCode'
    }),
    manufacturer () {
      let manufacturer = this.product.manufacturer
      if (this.attributes.manufacturer) {
        let option = this.attributes.manufacturer.options.find(av => {
          return av.value === manufacturer
        })
        if (option) {
          return option.label
        }
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped rel="stylesheet/stylus" lang="stylus">

</style>
```

Comment: where is your store of 'extraCart/attributeListByCode' be setting value?when you reload page,data in store will be cleared

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out to be the way I set the mutations was set to an object instead of using Vue.Set which then made these attributes reactive. Thanks for your guys' help.

Comment: A little more explanation on how you setup the mutations would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some condition checking:

`if (this.product && this.attributes.manufacturer) {}`

```
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      attributes: 'extraCart/attributeListByCode'
    }),
    manufacturer () {
      if (this.product && this.attributes.manufacturer) {
        let manufacturer = this.product.manufacturer
        let option = this.attributes.manufacturer.options.find(av => {
          return av.value === manufacturer
        })
        if (option) {
          return option.label
        }
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```